# how to rerender the view after calling viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift

Currently, I'm doing the following

viewDidLoad --> Fetching data asynchronously --> Filling up UILabels with that data

What happens is that sometimes that data is rendered incorrectly in the view. Is there a way to rerender the view after fetching the data asynchronously?

Comment: can you give more info on "rendered incorrectly". maybe you can also show the implementation of your data update

Answer (score 1):

You either can

1-

```
getdata { 
  present the vc
}
```

2-

```
presentTheVCController {
   showAlert
     getData {
      hideAlert
    }
  }
}
```